# What is the complexity of std::vector<T>::clear() when T is a primitive type?

Tags: vector, complexity-theory, unordered-map, primitive

I understand that the complexity of the clear() operation is linear in the size of the container, because the destructors must be called. But what about primitive types (and POD)? It seems the best thing to do would be to set the vector size to 0, so that the complexity is constant.

If this is possible, is it also possible for std::unordered_map?

Answer (score 11):

> It seems the best thing to do would be to set the vector size to 0, so that the complexity is constant.

In general, the complexity of [resizing a vector to zero](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/) is linear in the number of elements currently stored in the `vector`. Therefore, setting `vector`'s size to zero offers no advantage over calling `clear()` - the two are essentially the same.

However, at least one implementation (libstdc++, source in [`bits/stl_vector.h`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00182_source.html)) gives you an O(1) complexity for primitive types by employing partial template specialization.

The implementation of `clear()` navigates its way to the `std::_Destroy(from, to)` function in [`bits/stl_construct.h`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00530_source.html), which performs a non-trivial compile-time optimization: it declares an auxiliary template class `_Destroy_aux` with the template parameter of type `bool`. The class has a *partial specialization* for `true` and an *explicit specialization* for `false`. Both specializations define a single static function called `__destroy`. In case the template parameter is `true`, the function body is empty; in case the parameter is `false`, the [body contains a loop invoking `T`'s destructor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00530_source.html) by calling `std::_Destroy(ptr)`.

The trick comes on [line 136](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00530_source.html):

```
std::_Destroy_aux<__has_trivial_destructor(_Value_type)>::
__destroy(__first, __last);
```

The auxiliary class is instantiated based on the result of the `__has_trivial_destructor` check. The checker returns `true` for built-in types, and `false` for types with non-trivial destructor. As the result, the call to `__destroy` becomes a no-op for `int`, `double`, and other POD types.

The `std::unordered_map` is different from the `vector` in that it may need to delete structures that represent "hash buckets" of POD objects, as opposed to deleting objects themselves<sup>*</sup>. The optimization of `clear` to `O(1)` is possible, but it is heavily dependent on the implementation, so I would not count on it.

---

<sup>*</sup> The exact answer depends on the implementation: hash tables implementing [*collision resolution*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) based on open addressing (linear probing, quadratic probing, etc.) may be able to delete all buckets in `O(1)`; implementations based on separate chaining would have to delete buckets one-by-one, though.

Comment: Is this by any chance true for `resize`?

Comment: @Quimby Yes. clear reuses the logic of resizing the vector down.

Answer (score 0):

gcc's version of `std::_Destroy`,  which is what is eventually used by `clear()`, tries to template on on whether the type has a trivial destructor, so in that case the complexity is constant even without an optimisation pass. However I don't know how well the template works.