# std::vector<int>::clear, constant time?

Tags: c++, vector, primitive-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the complexity of std::vector<T>::clear() when T is a primitive type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235975/what-is-the-complexity-of-stdvectortclear-when-t-is-a-primitive-type)

If I have a `std::vector` with a primitive type, and I call `clear()` (this way `push_back` starts at the beginning of the `capacity`), is the `clear()` call going to be completed in constant time or linear time? The documentation says it destroys all the elements, but if the element is an int, there shouldn't be anything to destroy, right?

---

edit:
I found a duplicate that has a poster who explains in detail that the implementation can check whether the destructor is trivial, and gives an example of one compiler that has that check (GCC).

> [What is the complexity of std::vector<T>::clear() when T is a primitive type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235975/what-is-the-complexity-of-stdvectortclear-when-t-is-a-primitive-type)

Comment: You can't assume that, but it will almost certainly be the case with any respectable implementation.

Comment: It should be linear. Because C++ have to clear item one by one.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: Why's that then?

Comment: See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) Its linear.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: That website is not authoritative. The C++ standard is. Why do you say "C++ [has] to clear item one by one"? `delete[]` exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how the vector is implemented, but an array of objects with trivial destructors (which includes PODs like built-in integral types such as `int`) should be able to be deallocated safely with a single call to `vector<T>::allocator_type::deallocate` without looping over the elements and individually invoking destructors.  An implementation of `std::vector` can use `type_traits` or compiler internals to determine if `T` has a trivial destructor, and deallocate the internal array accordingly.  You'll need to check the source code of your implementation to find out what it does, but most mainstream implementations of `std::vector` will give you constant-time deallocation for types with trivial destructors (or at least constant time for integral types and other PODs).

Comment: If allocation is not constant time? why would de-allocation be constant ?

Comment: Because deallocation can be implemented as a single operation if `T` has a trivial destructor.

Comment: See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear)

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im, pushing an object may require to reallocate and copy all items. This is a linear time operation. If there's still free room in the vector, pushing an object is a constant-time operation.

Comment: @zneak in that case it depends on the size of container.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im, that doesn't matter.  That's just a guess or a generalization by whoever wrote the article on `cppreference.com`.  It's not authoritative or a quote from the standard.  The OP asked a question about *implementation* and the fact of the matter is that `std::vector` can be implemented with constant-time deallocation if `T` has a trivial destructor.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im, _inserting_ in a vector is constant time if the reserved size is larger than the number of elements, so it does depend on two variables. Clearing, on the other hand, doesn't depend on either the actual size or reserved size of the vector. It's a linear-time operation if you have to call destructors. But if you only have trivial destructors to call (for instance, with an `int` vector), it's possible to optimize the implementation of the vector to skip that step. If you can, the clear operation effectively becomes constant-time, as Charles explained.

Comment: @zneak See 23.1.1 [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf). More clearly on 23.1 in table 72.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im 17.1.3.3 clause 5: "Complexity requirements specified in the library clauses are upper bounds, and implementations that provide better complexity guarantees satisfy the requirements."

Answer (score 2):

The standard makes no guarantees about the complexity of `std::vector::clear`, though you'd expect the operation to be linear in the container's size for complex element types, and constant for PODs.

Comment: I'm sure it guarantees at worst linear complexity, doesn't it?

Comment: @K-ballo: I'd have thought so, but I can't find that stated.

Comment: Weird, it does for _associative_ and _unordered_ containers, must be an oversight...

Comment: There is an implicit complexity given that `clear()` is defined as `erase(begin(),end())`, and `erase` for `vector`s has _linear complexity_

Comment: @K-ballo: I can't find anywhere that requires that equivalence between `clear` and `erase` for `std::vector`. Where did you find it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `clear()` is `erase(begin(),end())`. See `23.1.1` of C++ standard

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: In C++11, there is no 23.1.1, and 23.1/1 simply says `This Clause describes components that C++ programs may use to organize collections of information.`. Now in _C++03_ (table 67) this equivalence is mandated as you point out. Deliberate omision from C++11 to make the implementers' lives easier? C.2.12 doesn't mention it (go figure)

Comment: @Lightness See [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf). Its in table 70 here.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: That is not a standard; it's also over seven years old. Please, we are discussing the current, actual, C++ standard.

Comment: I'm using the default C++11 compiler in Xcode for an iOS application, if that helps.