# Is the time complexity of `std::vector<T>::clear` *really* not specified?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, std

During the proceedings of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094302/stdvectorintclear-constant-time), it came to light that there appear to be no time complexity requirements placed on `std::vector<T>::clear` by the C++ standard.

Table 100 under 23.2.3 says:

> Destroys all elements in `a`. Invalidates all references, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of `a` and may invalidate the past-the-end iterator. post: `a.empty()` returns `true`

And... that's it. There's no entry for it specifically under 23.3.6, and no *explicit* indication that the following applies to `clear`:

> `[C++11: 23.3.6.1/1]:` A vector is a sequence container that supports random access iterators. In addition, **it supports (amortized) constant time insert and erase operations at the end; insert and erase in the middle take linear time**. Storage management is handled automatically, though hints can be given to improve efficiency. *[..]*

So... is this really true? Or have I simply missed it?

Comment: See _23.3.6.5/4_, still looking for `clear` as `erase(begin(),end())` for _sequences_...

Comment: @K-ballo: Where is that equivalence mandated?

Comment: I said I'm still looking for it :P

Comment: @K-ballo: Oh that's what you meant =) Yeah, I've been looking for it too... without success.......

Comment: It's there for associative containers (table 102), and their unordered friends have linear `clear` (table 103), but nothing for sequences....

Comment: Table 67 in C++03 mandated it. Dropped from C++11 with no mention under C.2.12.

Comment: I'd say that's enough for you to fill a defect report

Comment: @K-ballo: I'll wait for litb to come along and let him do it ;)

Comment: Well the minimum is O(n) for non POD (as you have to call the destructor for all the elements in the array) and O(1) for POD. But why would you want to impose limits?

Comment: Doesn't destroying every element imply O(N)? (It can't possibly be more than O(N), right?)

Comment: @usr: What's involved in destroying a block of `int`s other than freeing the memory it takes up?

Comment: @Loki: It's imposed for every type of container other than sequence.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I get your point but it could be an arbitrary element type, couldn't it?

Comment: @usr: The standard library is based on templates so there's absolutely no reason it can't specialise for POD element types.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seems to be an unintended consequence of [DR 704](http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-defects.html#704) (and the related [DR 1301](http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-closed.html#1301)) which removed the wording saying `clear()` was equivalent to `erase(begin(), end())` because `erase()` requires MoveAssignable, which isn't needed when erasing every element.  Removing the definition in terms of `erase()` also removes the complexity requirement.  That can probably be handled editorially; I've raised it with the committee.

N.B. `std::deque::clear()` and `std::forward_list::clear()` are also affected. `std::list::clear()` does have a complexity guarantee.

**Edit:** This has been resolved by [LWG Issue 2231](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2231) for C++14.

Comment: Erasing a trailing subset shouldn't require `MoveConstructible` either.  And what about `resize(0)`?  Perhaps it would be better to make `clear()` equivalent to `resize(0)`, thus getting `resize`'s complexity requirement.

Comment: Most sequences don't have `resize()`. Requirements on types (i.e. required concepts) are not specified in terms of values, but in terms of types. Concept-checking for `erase(i, j)` requires MoveAssignable (not MoveConstructible as I originally wrote, sorry), even if no moves will take place for the specific values `i` and `j`.

Comment: Hmmm.  It seems like there needs to be another operation (`truncate` perhaps) then, for erasure from specified iterator to the end.  Typically `erase(it, end()` is used for this, but a new operation wouldn't require `MoveAssignable` as `erase` does.

Comment: The sequence containers that require MoveAssignable for `erase()`, `vector` and `deque`, already provide `pop_back()` and `resize()` which meet that need. I don't think there's a current problem that would be solved by adding `truncate()`, the problem was that `clear()` was inappropriately defined in terms of `erase()` not that there is no way to clear non-MoveAssignable elements from the end of a sequence. The problem was one of a poor choice of wording in the standard, not missing functionality.