# Is `std::vector<primitive>::clear()` a constant time operation?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Calling `clear()` on a vector will call the destructors of whatever is stored in the vector, which is a linear time operation. But is this the case when the vector contains primitive types like `int` or `double`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the complexity of std::vector<T>::clear() when T is a primitive type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235975/what-is-the-complexity-of-stdvectortclear-when-t-is-a-primitive-type)

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::vector<int>::clear, constant time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094302/stdvectorintclear-constant-time)

Comment: What's the big-O of `N` repetitions of `O(0)`?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer is implementation dependent. It takes *at most* linear time, but some implementations may choose to optimize this.

Per '[Does clearing a vector affect its capacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882799/does-clearing-a-vector-affect-its-capacity)', neither MSVC nor G++ decrease the capacity of their vectors, even when `.clear` is called. Looking at the G++ headers, it is evident that `.clear` is constant-time with the default allocator, as long as the elements are scalar (primitive arithmetic types or pointers).

Comment: That seems consistent with the fact I cannot find anything about `vector::clear()` (or sequence containers' clear() for that matter) in the standard. Of course, it could be down to me not searching properly...

Comment: @juanchopanza: I have looked in the spec, and it really does seem to [be missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970747/is-the-complexity-of-vectorclear-unspecified). Note, though, that `erase(begin(), end())` is specified to take time equal to the amount of time needed to call every destructor.

Answer (score 2):

Think about this from the POV of how a `vector` is likely implemented. When you invoke:

```
 delete [] internalPtr;
```

What happens?

- The heap must reclaim a contiguous block of space
- destructors must fire or each object in internalPtr

The former must still happen for primitive types, but destructors don't exist for them. So `delete[]` will execute based entirely on how fast the heap can delete a block of memory

Comment: At least using the default allocator, `std::vector` won't use `delete [] internalPtr;`.

Answer (score 0):

In this link:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/

It says complexity of `clear()` is linear in size (destructions).

Comment: I cannot actually find anything in the C++11 standard to back this up. The link could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. it says that clear() is linear, but we also know that it calls the destructor of every item...

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/

What if the destructor call ist not linear?

However, on primitives the destructor-call is linear (or constant, this is not important unless it is not more than linear)

so yes, on primitives is clear() always a linear operation

Comment: Where does it say it is linear? I cannot find it anywhere in the C++11 standard, but I could be missing something.

Comment: OP asks specifically about primitives, which have trivial destructors.

Comment: @juanchopanza and nneonneo fixed