# Is the complexity of vector::clear unspecified?

Tags: c++, vector, language-lawyer

Per a discussion from [Is `std::vector<primitive>::clear()` a constant time operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970349/is-stdvectorprimitiveclear-a-constant-time-operation/14970508#14970508), it was noted that the C++ standard does not appear to specify the running time of `vector::clear`.

It specifies the running time of `list::clear` (linear; §23.3.5.4.5), `.clear` for both ordered (table 102) and unordered associative containers (table 103) (both linear). However, `vector::clear` appears to be missing (though other `vector` members, like `.data` and `.swap` appear to have specified complexity).

Is it really unspecified, or did I miss something?

Comment: Oversight or not, if it's not in there, doesn't that make it unspecified?

Comment: Yeah, that last statement didn't quite come out right. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: I remember tracing through the code of the standard library implementation supplied with my compiler, and figured out that the operation is, indeed, a no-op. I couldn't find anything in the standard, though, to indicate that the operation *must* be a no-op, though.

Comment: Well, `vector<scalar>::clear` is no-op for my G++ (which I checked as part of answering the linked question), but obviously `vector<classtype>::clear` cannot be a no-op since it must call destructors. Also, if you have a custom allocator then I think it cannot be a no-op either, though I'm not sure if that's mandated by the spec.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: clear() is *not* a no-op... at the very least it needs to ensure size is 0 (typically by setting a pointer to the last-used element (corresponding to `end()`), even for POD data types. For non-POD and size > 0, it needs to invoke in-place destructors on all the in-use elements: which will be linear complexity with their number. This complexity is mentioned at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/ - but I guess that's a common-sense deduction as I can't find anything in the Standard either.

Comment: Related SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14094336/777186

Comment: @nneonneo I knew I researched it at some point, and figured out that they did something clever! Here is [a link to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11235975/335858).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it really unspecified, or did I miss something?

**Yes**. At the moment, it is really unspecified.

[There is an **open library issue** for this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2231), whose text contains a link to a relevant Q&A on StackOverflow. The answer by [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely) to that question clarifies what has been going on.

According to the linked proposal, the complexity requirement of `clear()` should be made **linear** for all sequence containers. However, one must keep in mind that complexity requirements are just **upper bounds**. Per Paragraph 17.5.1.4/7 of the C++11 Standard:

> Complexity requirements specified in the library clauses are upper bounds, and implementations that provide better complexity guarantees satisfy the requirements.

This *allows* for possible optimizations, but does not mandate them.

Even when the linked proposal will be  accepted, we will not be allowed to assume that `clear()` has O(1) complexity for sequence containers of non-class elements, even though this seems to be a natural and common optimization strategy (and the answer by [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight) to **[this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235975/what-is-the-complexity-of-stdvectortclear-when-t-is-a-primitive-type)** confirms it).

Implementations will be allowed to adopt this strategy (per 17.5.1.4/7), but they won't be *required* to do so, because nowhere in the Standard such a constraint is (nor is it proposed to be) specified.